# Git - push local repo to a new remote repository

Tags: gitlab

I have a group in GitLab which has one repository under it in the remote and all works fine with that. However, I am now trying to create the following scenario:

1. Create new folder user1 and cd into it
2. git init
3. create new file
4. git add .
5. git commit -m "msg"
6. git remote add my-proj https://gitlab.com/my-proj/pro.git
7. git push --all -u https://gitlab.com/my-proj/pro.git

Sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't and I can't figure out what I am doing wrong, see example below:

This one worked well:

```
Gilad@DESKTOP-7SI7CJF MINGW64 /f/proj-uzip/my-proj/user1
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in F:/proj-uzip/my-proj/user1/.git/

Gilad@DESKTOP-7SI7CJF MINGW64 /f/proj-uzip/my-proj/user1 (master)
$ git add .

Gilad@DESKTOP-7SI7CJF MINGW64 /f/proj-uzip/my-proj/user1 (master)
$ git commit -m "msg"
[master (root-commit) c98d5d4] msg
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 New Text Document.txt

Gilad@DESKTOP-7SI7CJF MINGW64 /f/proj-uzip/my-proj/user1 (master)
$ git remote add my-proj https://gitlab.com/my-proj/pro.git

Gilad@DESKTOP-7SI7CJF MINGW64 /f/proj-uzip/my-proj/user1 (master)
$ git push --all -u https://gitlab.com/my-proj/pro.git
Enumerating objects: 3, done.
Counting objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 216 bytes | 216.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote:
remote:
remote: The private project my-proj/pro was successfully created.
remote:
remote: To configure the remote, run:
remote:   git remote add origin https://gitlab.com/my-proj/pro.git
remote:
remote: To view the project, visit:
remote:   https://gitlab.com/my-proj/pro
remote:
remote:
remote:
To https://gitlab.com/my-proj/pro.git
 * [new branch]      master -> master
Branch 'master' set up to track remote branch 'master' from 'https://gitlab.com/my-proj/pro.git'.
```

This one failed:

```
Gilad@DESKTOP-7SI7CJF MINGW64 /f/proj-uzip/my-proj/user1 - Copy
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in F:/proj-uzip/my-proj/user1 - Copy/.git/

Gilad@DESKTOP-7SI7CJF MINGW64 /f/proj-uzip/my-proj/user1 - Copy (master)
$ git add .

Gilad@DESKTOP-7SI7CJF MINGW64 /f/proj-uzip/my-proj/user1 - Copy (master)
$ git commit -m "hi"
[master (root-commit) 6c9fe76] hi
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 New Text Document.txt

Gilad@DESKTOP-7SI7CJF MINGW64 /f/proj-uzip/elixir-group/user1 - Copy (master)
$ git remote add ty https://gitlab.com/my-proj/ty.git

Gilad@DESKTOP-7SI7CJF MINGW64 /f/proj-uzip/elixir-group/user1 - Copy (master)
$ git push --all -u https://gitlab.com/my-proj/ty.git
remote: You are not allowed to push code to this project.
fatal: unable to access 'https://gitlab.com/my-proj/ty.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

I did them both one after the other, same process not sure why sometimes it works and sometimes not

Comment: Please check if you have permission to push in `master` branch on the project `ty.git`

Comment: I have permission on the PROJECT, there is no ty.git on the gitlab server until I push it and then it should be created. I have a local repo BEFORE I have any remote repo

Comment: All of this stuff is strictly up to GitLab. Git just sends the request as usual, and GitLab then look at who you claim to be and whether you seem to have the password or key or whatever so as to *believe* that you *are* who you claim to be. They then use the "you are that person" information to look up what permissions you have. All the control knobs are set in GitLab (I don't actually use GitLab myself so I don't know *where* in GitLab, just that Git doesn't have such knobs).

Comment: This part is pure guess: I would bet that GitLab have a feature where some path names are allowed for "create new repository project automatically" and other path names are dis-allowed. The projects where your initial `git push` creates a new one automatically are in the first set, and the projects where your initial `git push` fails are in the second. But it could also depend on whether you claim to be whoever you claim to be *via* https vs ssh, for instance (but both your examples here use https, hence my guess).

Comment: It is something to do with GitLab repos, I uploaded my answer since I found the issue after a few hours :(

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the issue is with GitLab preservation of old deleted repositories. What happened is that my repository was already created some time ago and I deleted it, however, it is still in 'Pending Deletion' state which I assume means that GitLab still sees it as active in some way.

So once I tried to create a new repository with the same name GitLab told me I can't access it, but once I created a new repository that wasn't been created before it worked.

So I guess this is how it works in GitLab but I find it weird that they are working this way.